# Is there a way to differentiate between chars and integers using keyListener methods in Java?

Tags: java, event-handling, keyboard-events

I'm currently trying to use different Java event handlers to do stuff for my university, but when I tried to write a programme that separates the user's input into chars and integers and put each type in a different textfield I just didn't know what methods to use!
So I would really appreciate it if anyone could give me a way to do so.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Character.isDigit(TheChar)` true if integer

`Character.isLetter(TheChar)` true if letter

**Edit** : full working code to show if the pressed key is number or letter

```
    textField1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            super.keyPressed(e);
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                label.setText("number");
            } else if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                label.setText("letter");
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: The `char` type is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the over 140,000 characters defined in Unicode. I suggest changing your Answer to use the versions of those methods taking a integer [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) number instead.

Comment: public void keyPressed (KeyEvent event){
  char c = event.getKeyChar();
  String s;
  while(T1.size()<=10){
  if (Character.isDigit(c)){
   s = Character.toString(c);
   T2.setText("nimber");
  }
  else if (Character.isLetter(c))
   s = Character.toString(c);
   T2.setText("letter");
 }
now this is the kwyPressed method. I want to type something in the first TextField and the second TextField shows the type of character I typed! but it's getting only the first keyboard press and ignoring the rest, what do you think is wrong with the code?

Comment: @NajeeShaheen I've looked into your code first of all you don't need that while loop it doesn't make any sense, other than that the code works fine 
it could be something about how you're using the listener 
I'll update the answer with full code
upvote and mark as answer if it solves your problem :)

Comment: Okay it worked! but what if I wanted to set the text to the specific letter or number that's been typed?!
I tried adding these few lines to the Code:
@Override 
 public void keyPressed (KeyEvent event){
  char c = event.getKeyChar();
  String s;
  if (Character.isDigit(c)){
   s = Character.toString(c);
   label1.setText(String.format("You're entering numbers:\n%s", s));
  }
  else if (Character.isLetter(c))
   s = Character.toString(c);
   label2.setText(String.format("You're entering letters:\n%s", s))
 }